# Как равномерно растянуть элементы меню

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Xamarin.Android.
Сделал кастомное меню. Точнее табы. 
Использовал разные библиотеки, ничего в итоге не подошло, решил сделать сам.
Подскажите, как растянуть их равномерно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал внутренние и внешние отступы с процентами, но всё криво. Есть ли решение типа Flexbox?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout

Comment: Xamarin.Forms не подойдёт, пишу на нативном. Xamarin.Android, думал в тегах укажу, народ поймёт.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте родительскому элементу

```css
display: flex; /* Добавляет свойства флекс контейнера для блока */
justify-content: space-between; /* Выравнивает все дочерние элементы по ширине блока */
align-items: center; /* Выравнивает все дочерние элементы по центру, относительно высоты блока */
```

Comment: разве Xamarin как то связан с web вообще и CSS стилями в частности, это же не ReactNative и прочие Cordov-ы? как бы в Xamarin-e такое есть, [но синтаксис другой](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout)

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо за наводку! Помогла эта библиотека https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout